# How to open view controller after data has been loaded into model object?

Tags: objective-c, json, model, nsdata

How can I check if the `NSData dataWithContentsOfURL`parsing in my secondary thread are finished? When every image is finished I want to open my view controller. Not before. Now I can open my view controller directly, and sometimes if I'm to quick my table view has no images, because they're not finished yet. Any ideas?

The following code happens in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in AppDelegate. Im using the SBJSON framework for parsing.

(Im using the storyboard in this project so there's no code for opening the first view controller)

Code:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"json_template" ofType:@"json"];
NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: filePath  encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: nil];
SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *json = [jsonParser objectWithString: contents];
tabs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
jsonParser = nil;

//parsing json into model objects
for (NSString *tab in json)
{
    Tab *tabObj = [[Tab alloc] init];
    tabObj.title = tab;

    NSDictionary *categoryDict = [[json valueForKey: tabObj.title] objectAtIndex: 0];
    for (NSString *key in categoryDict)
    {

        Category *catObj = [[Category alloc] init];
        catObj.name = key;


        NSArray *items = [categoryDict objectForKey:key];

        for (NSDictionary *dict in items)
        {
            Item *item = [[Item alloc] init];
            item.title = [dict objectForKey: @"title"];
            item.desc = [dict objectForKey: @"description"];
            item.url = [dict objectForKey: @"url"];

            if([dict objectForKey: @"image"] != [NSNull null])
            {

                dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0 ), ^(void)
                               {
                                   NSURL *imgUrl = [NSURL URLWithString: [dict objectForKey: @"image"]];
                                   NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: imgUrl];

                                   dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
                                   {
                                       item.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];

                                   });
                               });
            }
            else
            {
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"standard3.png"];
                item.image = image;
            }

            [catObj.items addObject: item];

        }

        [tabObj.categories addObject: catObj]; 
    }

    [tabs addObject: tabObj];


}

//sort array 
[tabs sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2){


    Tab *r1 = (Tab*) obj1;
    Tab *r2 = (Tab*) obj2;

    return [r1.title caseInsensitiveCompare: r2.title];

}];



/***** END PARSING JSON *****/

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{
                    UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 0.0f)],
                    UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"GreatLakesNF" size:20.0f]
 }];

UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
UIImage *backButtonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"backBtn.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

UIImage *backButtonSelectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"backBtn_selected.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButtonSelectedImage forState: UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


return YES;
```

Also, if this way of parsing is bad, please tell me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't use such way of downloading any content from remote host.
There are lots of libraries like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), [ASIHTTPRequest](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/tree)

which work around CFNetwork or NSURLConnection to handle such things as redirects, error handling etc.
So you should definitely move to one of those (or implement your own based on NSURLConnection).

As a direct answer to your question:
You should use some kind of identifier for counting downloaded images (i.e. for-loop iteration counter) and pass it via +[UINotificationCenter defaultCenter] as a parameter of some custom notification.

Example (assuming that you are blocking current thread by +[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"someCustomNotificationClassName" object:nil userInfo:@{ @"counter" : @(i) }];
}
```

More expanded example of NSNotification-based approach:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // subscribing for notification
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleDataDownload:) name:@"someCustomNotificationClassName" object:nil];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    // unsubscribing from notification on -dealloc
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

#pragma mark - downloading delegation

- (void)handleDataDownload:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    int counter = [userInfo[@"counter"] intValue];
    if (counter == 10) {
        // do some work afterwards
        // assuming that last item was downloaded
    }
}
```

Also you can use callback technique to manage handling of download state:

```
void (^callback)(id result, int identifier) = ^(id result, int identifier) {
    if (identifier == 10) {
        // do some work afterwards
    }
};

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, kNilOptions), ^{
        // some downloading stuff which blocks thread
        id data = nil;
        callback(data, i);
    });
}
```